# Spec Errors validation With RSpec + CouchRest_Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I trying to spec validations of my model this is my model

```
 class Account < CouchRest::Model::Base
         property :user, String 
         property :password, String
         property :name, String
         property :email, String
         property :activate, TrueClass, :default => true
         validates_presence_of :user, :password, :name, :email
         validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..15, :if => lambda{|account| !account.password.blank? }
         validates_uniqueness_of :user, :if => (lambda{|account| !account.user.blank?})
  end
```

and into my model_spec i'm trying to do this

```
account = Account.new
account.should have(1).error_on_presence_of(:email)
```

But instead 1 error, I'm getting 6 
 
I think that might be caused by validates of couchrest but not sure.

Can someone clarify this for me please?

P.S.: If I validate the same model into console I get 4 errors corresponding the four  empty properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're expecting 1 error, but there are actually 6. To figure out what is in the error hash, you can set a temporary expectation:

```
`account.errors.should == {}
```

Then the example will fail and RSpec will print the value of the error hash, and you can see which errors are actually being generated.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I realized that the method .valid? somehow it isn't been  called, the result of 'account.errors.should == {}' are all properties  of model plus couchrest-type. So I just worked around, validating field by field.

Comment: `account.errors` would include the account record, then any messages, so it will never be empty. To see just the messages, look at the `full_messages` array instead:  `account.errors.full_messages.should == []`.